# What is happening in the "Depth of Field" specials?

Tags: love-chunibyo-and-other-delusions

The Depth of Field specials (included with the BD/DVDs) depict Dekomori and Rika going at it against each other in giant, magically-powered CG mechs. What's the story behind this?

Are they roleplaying (while playing some game?) something or is this set in an alternate universe?

[image: Look at the pretty glyphs!]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Depth of Field: Phase 6, it is revealed that Rikka and Dekomori are engaged in some sort of role-play thing in the clubroom. They seem to be pretending that the cardboard boxes they wear are mechas.

[image: Rikka and Dekomori sit in the clubroom, wearing cardboard boxes]

The preceding episodes of Depth of Field depict the way they imagine their role-play fight to take place.